# Can Reinforcement Learning be used for UAV waypoint control?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, algorithm, learning-algorithms

I want to make a drone which can follow static and dynamic waypoints. I am a total beginner in the drone field so I can't figure out that should I use Reinforcement Learning or any other learning methods for the drone to make it follow both static and dynamic waypoints. If RL is the best choice for the task, then how would I go about training the model and upload it to the flight controller. And if RL is not required, then what should I use in order to achieve this task.

Please let me know how should I begin with this task

Comment: You shouldnt use RL, you should use some trajectory planning algorithm that gives you trajectory from the waypoints and then use  some controller to follow trajectory (simple PID will suffice). There is numerous literature ([here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1474667015402812) is one example), look it up on Google scholar by typing keywords like 'UAV', 'trajectory', 'waypoints'.

Comment: Okay I will look at it, thanks!

Comment: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8795855

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.05057.pdf